# Checking if process is completed (python)

Tags: python, process

How do I check if a process has stopped running in python? I don't care if it is a zombie process, just if it has stopped running (syscall exit) This only has to work on linux. I have checked out `psutil`, but the `STATE_STOPPED` and `STATE_DEAD` don't seem to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> pidof -- find the process ID of a running program.

pidof will have his exit code to zero if at least one process by that name is running, else it will be one.

You can do a little bash script like this:

```
if pidof python > /dev/null;
then
    echo 'At least one is running'
else
    echo 'No process is running'
fi
```

I am pipe-ing the output to /dev/null just to avoid having the PID of the found process being printed, but this is optional.

EDIT: If you want to be able to do it from python, just do the same thing:

```
import os

if os.system("pidof man > /dev/null") == 0:
    print('At least one is running')
else:
    print('No process is running')
```

Comment: I thought of running `ps -e | grep PID_OR_NAME` but this is also good,

Comment: @Enzo Caceres it seems to not be able to see a certain process, but i know it exists by running ps -a

Comment: Do you have any exemple ?

Comment: ok so i have a python script, which runs execl to run a bash script, and it doesn't see the bash script

Comment: Are you sure that you are running it with bash ? maybe its sh ? or zsh ? Try to replace the content of your bash script by `while true; do sleep 1; done;` and test again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216345/discussion-between-ruiqi-li-and-enzo-caceres).